# How to set vm arguments from inside of groovy (gradle) to Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, groovy, build.gradle

I want to set vm arguments from gradle:

eg To start Java app I do:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

I want to do same but from gradle not from comand line

I tried diffrent variants and it does not work:

```
System.properties['spring.profiles.active'] = "dev"
System.setProperty('spring.profiles.active',"dev")
```

How to set `System.properties` form Gradle? I need runs spring app on tomcat as `.war` file and I cant pass it as system variable

I need it because
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

> 69.6 Set the active Spring profiles
>
> The Spring Environment has an API for this, but normally you would set
>   a System property (spring.profiles.active) or an OS environment
>   variable (SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE). E.g. launch your application with a
>   -D argument (remember to put it before the main class or jar archive):
>
> $ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production
>   demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>
> In Spring Boot you can also set the active profile in
>   application.properties, e.g.
>
> spring.profiles.active=production
>
> A value set this way is replaced by the System property or environment
>   variable setting, but not by the SpringApplicationBuilder.profiles()
>   method. Thus the latter Java API can be used to augment the profiles
>   without changing the defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
bootRun {
    systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'dev'
}
```

I found answer here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/592